# CtrlP searches entire machine

Tags: plugin-ctrlp, macos

I use CtrlP with vim, installed it with [Plug](https://github.com/junegunn/vim-plug) and have it set up mostly to default settings. Whenever I use the plugin though, it seems to search through all my files on my entire machine. So instead of looking for the nearest `.git` directory or just using the current working directory, it literally searches everywhere.

While I have been searching for the issue several times, I can't seem to find any solution. I vaguely remember finding something related to Mac but the fix not working for me.

I barely changed any of the CtrlP configuration settings, but here's what I have:

```
let g:ctrlp_cmd = 'CtrlPMixed'
let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'ra'
```

I'm running vim 7.4 on Mac OS X 10.10.2, here's a bit of `vim --version`:

```
VIM - Vi IMproved 7.4 (2013 Aug 10, compiled Feb 10 2015 09:51:02)
MacOS X (unix) version
Included patches: 1-488
Compiled by Homebrew
```

Comment: What directory are you starting CtrlP from? If you start it from your home directory, it will have to search a lot of unneeded files.

Comment: I start Vim from within my projects git repository. Usually the root directory of the repo, sometimes in a subdirectory.

Comment: Is the behavior also reproducible with `:CtrlP` or `:CtrlPCurWD`?

Comment: Ah, now we're on to something. `:CtrlP` and `CtrlPCurWD` function as expected: they search the correct directories!

Comment: I'm not sure if that's a bug in `:CtrlPMixed` in that case. I don't use it myself. Perhaps you can file an issue over at [ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim](https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim).

Comment: Hm, thanks anyway! I've opened an issue, hopefully it'll get fixed soon...

Comment: CtrlP has been dead for over a year.

Comment: @romainl the github repo was last updated 19 days ago? Do you recommend any alternatives?

Comment: Latest commit was in july 2013. You can find a link to a supposedly more active fork in the issue tracker.

Comment: yeah, @akshay linked that a few comments above, it's at https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim and I've installed it, but that still doesn't solve my issue.

Answer (score 1):

It's possibly your working path mode - check the ctrlp help for `g:ctrlp_working_path_mode`. I'm not sure what the default is, but I seem to recall that when I didn't explicitly set it I also got weirdness. Since I am mostly working in source controlled projects I use `let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'r'` but otherwise using `let g:ctrlp_working_path_mode = 'c'` might also help.